# Database design suggestion about drug store

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to design a databse of a drug store. Suppose I have 5 product i.e p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5. Same product may have different expiry date, for example suppose I have 10 qty of p1 product whose expiry date is 1/1/2016, and if  i purchese again 20 qty of p1 product its total qty will 30. but those product (newly purchesed) expiry date may not be same.Then how to maintain those product based on expiry date?

*Initial design*

table product

**Product {ID, pName, pCode, ExpDate}**

Comment: What about charge number?

Comment: I could not understand

Comment: Usually drugs have a charge namber. And expiry date depends on it.

Comment: My client asked me to do that. I don't know about drug related things. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more table associated with your `product` table.

e.g.

```
Product
id  name    code
1   Aspirin 554
2   Depon   334

Product_item
id  product_id  exp_date
1   1           01/2016
2   1           02/2016
3   1           03/2016
4   2           01/2016
```

So each `product_item` will have its own expiration date without duplicate data.

Comment: I' m glad that I helped you.